# Microsoft Robotics studio

Tags: robotics

To Develop using the Microsoft robotics studio,

do I have to use only Microsoft hardware to program?

Or can I use the Microsoft robotics studio and use some standard serial based protocol to send to  other robots?

Is there any modeling tool to help visualization of the robot's axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can use any type of hardware (actuators, sensors, etc). They provide adapters for the most commonly used in the market, but you can write your own "service" for your custom hardware.

They also provide a physics engine (based on Ageia if I'm not mistaken) where you can control your virtual robot exactly like the real one would.

Comment: sad that they've frozen its development for long time now